# Do i need to extend Adapter Class 'here'?

Tags: java, events, user-interface, adapter

This is my snippet :

```
tf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
            getEnter(ke);
     }
  });
```

There are 3 methods in `KeyListener interface`.But i want to use only one method i.e `keyTyped()`
 How can i do this?
 (Do i need to extend AdapterClass? if yes, how?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to extend the `KeyAdapter` class.  It provides (empty) implementations of all the `KeyListener` methods.  You have to override the one(s) you need and the empty implementations will satisfy the interface's contract.  You'd extend it the same way as in your code:

```
tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
             getEnter(ke);
     }
  });
```

As the Javadoc itself for KeyAdapter says:

> Extend this class to create a KeyEvent listener and override the methods for the events of interest. (If you implement the KeyListener interface, you have to define all of the methods in it. This abstract class defines null methods for them all, so you can only have to define methods for events you care about.)

Comment: Notice that using Adapter classes is more dangerous than using listeners, as you may make a mistake with the method names that you are overriding, which will mean your method isn't called, but it will compile. As an example look at Quantum's example. He has overriden the method incorrectly, and so the key listener will not work. This obviously can't happen with interfaces. If using 1.5 or greater always put @Override annotations on them to make sure that you did it right.

Comment: @  MeBigFatGuy i just saw ! How does the program compile **without error** when i give a wrong name to a function ?

Comment: Edited to fix the method name typo :)

Comment: @Suhail well, you are just creating another class. As such you can add as many methods to that class as you like, even ones that are very similar to the ones defined by the Listener. The only requirement is that the methods defined by the interface be implemented. But the Adapter takes care of that for you. It implements all the methods, but of course does nothing in those methods. That's why it compiles.